# How to find the second occurence of .find_element_by_class_name?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have tried,

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('("my_class")[1]')
browser.find_element_by_class_name('("my_class")[position()=1]')
browser.find_element_by_class_name("my_class")[1]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### The "easy" answer

The simple way to get what you want is to use the plural form of the locator method you are already using, `find_elements_by_class_name()`. The plural forms return a list instead of just the first match so in your case you would use

```
find_elements_by_class_name("my_class")[1]
```

The `find_elements_*` method returns a list and the `[1]` at the end specifies to return only the second item in the collection (the index starts at 0).

---

#### What I would use

I generally don't use `*_by_class_name()` because it's rare that I'm only looking for a class. I typically at least specify the tag name also, e.g. `div.my_class`. Another option, and the one I typically use, is a CSS selector. CSS selectors should be preferred over XPath because of better performance, better support, etc.*

An example

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3">123</div>
<div class="class2">2</div>
<div class="class3">3</div>
<div class="class1 class2">12</div>
<div class="class1 class3">13</div>
<div class="class1">1</div>
<div class="class2 class3">23</div>
```

If you had the above HTML and wanted the second instance of "class1", you would use

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.class1")[1]
```

Another advantage of CSS selectors over XPath is that CSS selectors look for the class name amongst multiple class names on an element where XPath can only do a text search which can lead to false or missed matches. The CSS selector above would return 4 total elements: "123", "12", "13", "1". The index `[1]` returns only the second instance, "12".

If you used the XPath that DebanjanB suggested,

```
//*[@class='my_class'][position()=2]
```

it would return nothing. That's because there's only one element that has the exact string "my_class" as the class. It misses all the other elements that contain but are not only "my_class". You could improve it to find them all but it still has all the downfalls of XPath vs CSS selectors, it's much longer, and so on...

See the [Selenium-python docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) for more info on ways to find elements.

*If you need more details on the why, there's a number of articles already addressing this or look through the videos on the [Selenium Conference YT channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/seleniumconf) and watch some of the keynote addresses by Simon Stewart or other Selenium contributors.

---

#### Don't forget

1. You may need to use a wait if the page is slow to load.
2. On some lazy loading pages you will need to scroll the page to get the additional elements to load.